# Segmentation fault with talend start

Tags: jvm, centos, talend, jvm-crash

This question could be repeated, But this is some unique problem in talend and my eclipse is working fine by using same JVM.

I have been working on Linux environment and I recently downloaded the Talend ETL Open studio zip file for the data integration project.

**Configuraitons**
Linux 64 bit
Java 64 bit(1.6.0_24)
Talend Version : TOS_DI-r104014-V5.3.1
Processor : Intel core-i-7

[Talend data integration link](http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration)

It is possible to run Java programs with eclipse and all other java processors without any problems.

But I unable to run **TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64** and getting following error.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000301f60e01c, pid=31589, tid=140448056850176
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0xe01c]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fbc98008800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=31590, stack(0x00007fbc9c79b000,0x00007fbc9c89c000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000004

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000032, RDX=0x0000000000000882
RSP=0x00007fbc9c898790, RBP=0x00007fbc31561000, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00007fbc3158e8f6
R8 =0x0000000001e92a23, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x00007fbc9c8985b0, R11=0x00007fbc9c8985b0
R12=0x0000000002848cf0, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007fbc980a01f0, R15=0x0000000000000002
RIP=0x000000301f60e01c, EFL=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

RBX=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

RCX=0x0000000000000032
0x0000000000000032 is pointing to unknown location

RDX=0x0000000000000882
0x0000000000000882 is pointing to unknown location

RSP=0x00007fbc9c898790
0x00007fbc9c898790 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbc98008800
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fbc98008800 nid=0x7b66 runnable [0x00007fbc9c899000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

RBP=0x00007fbc31561000
0x00007fbc31561000: xul23.0.1+0 in /usr/lib64/xulrunner-last/libxul.so at 0x00007fbc31561000

RSI=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

RDI=0x00007fbc3158e8f6
0x00007fbc3158e8f6: <offset 0x2d8f6> in /usr/lib64/xulrunner-last/libxul.so at 0x00007fbc31561000

R8 =0x0000000001e92a23
0x0000000001e92a23 is pointing to unknown location

R9 =0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

R10=0x00007fbc9c8985b0
0x00007fbc9c8985b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbc98008800
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fbc98008800 nid=0x7b66 runnable [0x00007fbc9c899000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

R11=0x00007fbc9c8985b0
0x00007fbc9c8985b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbc98008800
"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007fbc98008800 nid=0x7b66 runnable [0x00007fbc9c899000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

R12=0x0000000002848cf0
0x0000000002848cf0 is pointing to unknown location

R13=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

R14=0x00007fbc980a01f0
0x00007fbc980a01f0 is pointing to unknown location

R15=0x0000000000000002
0x0000000000000002 is pointing to unknown location


Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fbc9c898790)
0x00007fbc9c898790:   0000000000000005 0000000000000000
0x00007fbc9c8987a0:   0000000000039820 0000000000000000
0x00007fbc9c8987b0:   0000000000000410 00007fbc33b0f1f8
0x00007fbc9c8987c0:   00007fbc9c898850 00007fbc984a64e0
0x00007fbc9c8987d0:   00007fbc984a5270 000000301f614715
0x00007fbc9c8987e0:   00007fbc321778db 0000000000000006
0x00007fbc9c8987f0:   0000000000000000 0000000005265c00
0x00007fbc9c898800:   00007fbc33ea63f0 00007fbc984abfb0
0x00007fbc9c898810:   fff880000000001c 00007fbc984a5270
0x00007fbc9c898820:   00000000000005bd 00007fbc321778f0
0x00007fbc9c898830:   00007fbc984a64e0 00007fbc32f7b926
0x00007fbc9c898840:   0000000000000000 0000000000000021
0x00007fbc9c898850:   00007ffff365a448 00007fbc31c9a303
0x00007fbc9c898860:   0000007c0000005b 000000301f60e545
0x00007fbc9c898870:   00000000000001b0 0000000000000008
0x00007fbc9c898880:   0000000000000080 00007fbc98000020
0x00007fbc9c898890:   00007fbc984a6798 00007fbc9c898aa0
0x00007fbc9c8988a0:   00007fbc984a64e0 0000000000000043
0x00007fbc9c8988b0:   00007fbc984a6798 00007fbc984a5ec0
0x00007fbc9c8988c0:   0000000000000001 000000301f612ca5
0x00007fbc9c8988d0:   00000000e8050ce8 00007fbc94ce6a01
0x00007fbc9c8988e0:   0000000000000038 00007fbc984a8dd0
0x00007fbc9c8988f0:   800000019c898970 000000301f821160
0x00007fbc9c898900:   ffffffff80000001 00007fbc9c898aa0
0x00007fbc9c898910:   00007fbc981f9468 0000000000000010
0x00007fbc9c898920:   00000000e75b00b8 0000000000000000
0x00007fbc9c898930:   00007fbc9c898b30 fffffffffffffffe
0x00007fbc9c898940:   00007fbc9ceda4af 0000000000000021
0x00007fbc9c898950:   00007fbc981ee450 000000301f60e1a6
0x00007fbc9c898960:   00007fbc9c89b6f8 00007fbc9c898af0
0x00007fbc9c898970:   00007fbc9c898ae8 00007fbc9c898aff
0x00007fbc9c898980:   000000301f612910 00007fbc9c898aa0 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000301f60e01c)
0x000000301f60e00c:   85 f6 74 0c 48 85 db 74 03 48 8b 03 48 03 46 08
0x000000301f60e01c:   0f b6 56 04 83 e2 0f 83 fa 0a 0f 84 7e 00 00 00 

Stack: [0x00007fbc9c79b000,0x00007fbc9c89c000],  sp=0x00007fbc9c898790,  free space=1013k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0xe01c]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/io/File;)Z+300
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+127
j  java.lang.Runtime.load0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V+57
j  java.lang.System.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;)Z+12
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+641
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initMozilla(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+128
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)Z+524
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+302
j  org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+51
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007fbc40511800 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=31614, stack(0x00007fbc7c997000,0x00007fbc7ca98000)]
  0x00007fbc408e6800 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31611, stack(0x00007fbc7cc2f000,0x00007fbc7cd30000)]
  0x00007fbc982db000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31609, stack(0x00007fbc7cd30000,0x00007fbc7ce31000)]
  0x00007fbc98240800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31608, stack(0x00007fbc7ce31000,0x00007fbc7cf32000)]
  0x00007fbc98258000 JavaThread "State Saver" [_thread_blocked, id=31607, stack(0x00007fbc7cf32000,0x00007fbc7d033000)]
  0x00007fbc980c0800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31605, stack(0x00007fbc7eb21000,0x00007fbc7ec22000)]
  0x00007fbc980be000 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31604, stack(0x00007fbc7ec22000,0x00007fbc7ed23000)]
  0x00007fbc980bb800 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31603, stack(0x00007fbc7ed23000,0x00007fbc7ee24000)]
  0x00007fbc980b9000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31602, stack(0x00007fbc7ee24000,0x00007fbc7ef25000)]
  0x00007fbc9809d000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31601, stack(0x00007fbc7ef25000,0x00007fbc7f026000)]
  0x00007fbc9809b000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31600, stack(0x00007fbc7f026000,0x00007fbc7f127000)]
=>0x00007fbc98008800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=31590, stack(0x00007fbc9c79b000,0x00007fbc9c89c000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007fbc98094800 VMThread [stack: 0x00007fbc7f127000,0x00007fbc7f228000] [id=31599]
  0x00007fbc980d3000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007fbc7ea20000,0x00007fbc7eb21000] [id=31606]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 152896K, used 133801K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000f2aa0000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 131072K, 92% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e765c098,0x00000000e8000000)
  from space 21824K, 57% used [0x00000000e8000000,0x00000000e8c4e5f0,0x00000000e9550000)
  to   space 21824K, 0% used [0x00000000f1550000,0x00000000f1550000,0x00000000f2aa0000)
 PSOldGen        total 349568K, used 0K [0x00000000a0000000, 0x00000000b5560000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 349568K, 0% used [0x00000000a0000000,0x00000000a0000000,0x00000000b5560000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 15532K [0x0000000080000000, 0x00000000814c0000, 0x00000000a0000000)
  object space 21248K, 73% used [0x0000000080000000,0x0000000080f2b018,0x00000000814c0000)

Dynamic libraries:
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 1969754                            /data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 fd:02 1969754                            /data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java
40503000-40524000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
80000000-814c0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
814c0000-a0000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
a0000000-b5560000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
b5560000-e0000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
e0000000-f2aa0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f2aa0000-100000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
301f600000-301f620000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 809853                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
```

/*
.....
.....
......Remaining codes not added--------------
*/

```
VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms512m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: /data/Software/TOS_DI-r104014-V5.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher /data/Software/TOS_DI-r104014-V5.3.1/TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64 -name TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64 --launcher.library /data/Software/TOS_DI-r104014-V5.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810/eclipse_1309.so -startup /data/Software/TOS_DI-r104014-V5.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar -exitdata 848019 -vm /data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /data/Software/TOS_DI-r104014-V5.3.1/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24
JRE_HOME=/data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24
PATH=/data/Software/apache-tomcat-6.0.13/bin:/data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24/bin:/data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24/bin:/data/Software/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/shared/bin
USERNAME=rk40332
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/amd64/server:/data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/amd64:/data/Software/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/lib64/xulrunner-last
SHELL=/bin/csh
DISPLAY=:0.0
HOSTTYPE=x86_64-linux
OSTYPE=linux
MACHTYPE=x86_64

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x791b30], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x791b30], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x640ba0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x640ba0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x640ba0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x643780], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x643380], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x643380], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x643380], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x643380], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

uname:Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.12 NPTL 2.12 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 10240, NOFILE 65535, AS infinity
load average:1.00 1.05 1.09

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       16212264 kB
MemFree:         2754752 kB
Buffers:          383776 kB
Cached:         10825656 kB
SwapCached:          272 kB
Active:          5194780 kB
Inactive:        7333968 kB
Active(anon):     855584 kB
Inactive(anon):   587876 kB
Active(file):    4339196 kB
Inactive(file):  6746092 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       8388600 kB
SwapFree:        8388236 kB
Dirty:               156 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1319544 kB
Mapped:           174108 kB
Shmem:            124140 kB
Slab:             745156 kB
SReclaimable:     685280 kB
SUnreclaim:        59876 kB
KernelStack:        4216 kB
PageTables:        40072 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    16494732 kB
Committed_AS:    3417092 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      389380 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359333020 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    532480 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        8192 kB
DirectMap2M:    16660480 kB


CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 16212264k(2754752k free), swap 8388600k(8388236k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_24-b07), built on Feb  2 2011 16:55:54 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)

time: Tue Sep 17 14:18:43 2013
elapsed time: 2 seconds
```

Please let us know the recent for this issue and how to resolve this. If this could be JVM issue, eclipse also should not work ?

Comment: I have downloaded and test with java 7 64 bit and with that jvm also I am getting same error. In the same time i have checked with different talend versions, that is open studio and professional versions and all the time getting this JVM cash issue.

Comment: How exactly do you reproduce this error? Could you tell us what steps you took to check a talend version and get the same error?

Comment: I have checked with Talend Open Studio for Data Integration v5.3.1

And also check with talend professional version 5.2

Comment: Steps
1. Download the talend studio by using given link. http://www.talend.com/download/data-integration

2. Click on TOS_DI-linux-gtk-x86_64 to start talend. Then getting above error....